# Are self-signed certificates still supported in modern browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, ssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed

AFAIK, it was a common scenario to buy a production SSL certificate for mydomain.com, and use a self-signed certificate (eg using java's keytool) for CN localhost to use during development.

In the interests of security, it seems that very recent versions of Firefox (33) and Chrome (39) may forbid this approach.

Is that correct? If so, what is the new-fangled approach these browsers expect you to take during development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, self-signed certificates are still supported by most mayor web browsers. However, it must be installed in the trust store of particular web browser (e.g. Firefox, Opera) or in the system certificate store (e.g. Internet Explorer, Chrome, Safari).

And currently there is no expectations to break this behavior, because many network-managed devices (routers, wireless AP, etc.) still use self-signed certificate to protect the traffic.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. With Firefox 33.1, Preferences-->Advanced-->Certificates-->View Certificates-->Server-->Exceptions, and attempting to add an exception for a localhost server on 8443 using a self-signed certificate, Firefox says "no information available". Seems like it might be related to PKIX and the inability to turn it off as of Firefox 33?

Comment: There should be a store for trusted root certificates. You need to put your certificate there first. And there might by an issue with "localhost" name, it may be prohibited.

Answer (score 0):

You can always get a signed but free certificate from StartSSL.com.
The free ones are valid for one year, the cons are:

- no free revocation process
- no free reissues
- only host.mydomain.com and mydomain.com will be listed in the certificate, no free certificates for dev.host.mydomain.com