# Jetty 9 cant work with self-signed certificate that generated by OpenSSL

Tags: ssl, https, jetty, jetty-9

I want to configure SSL on **jetty-distribution-9.2.9.v20150224**

I followed http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/configuring-ssl.html to configure SSL and generate certificate

The problem is:
If I use the keystore generated by Keytool:

`keytool -keystore keystore -alias jetty -genkey -keyalg RSA`

and configure ssl and https modules to start.ini, Jetty works correctly.

However , the certificate extracted from keystore can’t be trusted by browser. So I want to create self-signed certificate using Openssl

My **Openssl version is 0.9.8**, and I generated keystore in following steps:

`openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key`

`openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr`

`openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in mn-server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt`

`keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias server  -file server.crt -keystore truststore.keystore`

However, this **truststore.keystore** can't work. Http works correctly, but I’m not able to access to https. There's no special exception throw out, and when checking 8443 port, it's already initialized.

Am I missing some jetty configuration ? or the certificate generated  is generated incorrect?

---

After debug, I see this **no cipher suites in common** exception

```
%%Initialized:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
qtp1811075214-27, fatal error: 40: no cipher suites in common
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
%% Invalidated:  [Session-1, SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL]
qtp1811075214-27, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
qtp1811075214-27, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
qtp1811075214-27, fatal: engine already closed.  Rethrowing    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: no cipher suites in common
```

The Signature algorithm I'm using is SHA1withRSA , and my Java version is  "1.8.0_25"

Comment: [Self signed certificates are still supported by browsers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27125108/are-self-signed-certificates-still-supported-in-modern-browsers), even with keytool (the preferred tool for working with SSL on Java)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was solved by upgrade spring-ws-core version to 2.2.x

And I also upgrade openssl to 1.0.1k

Comment: I didn't see any mention that he was using Spring